# nginx is trying to serve my backend as a static site

Tags: nginx

My frontend is a static site served at location `/`, while my backend is a REST API at location `/core/`. I've configured `nginx.conf` to reverse proxy the backend, but according to the logs, it's attempting to serve it as a static site.

```
2018/12/17 08:47:32 [error] 6#6: *12 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/core/v1/api/user/login" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location ^~ /core/ {
            proxy_pass http://my-named-backend:8080/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location / {
            # Nothing to put here since the dist/ files are
            # /usr/share/nginx/html is automatically served.
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Remove trailing slash from your backend declaration.

Comment: Have you tested the configuration using `nginx -T`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky tried it, that didn't work.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, the config is reported to be valid.

Comment: The rest of your config seems ok to me, maybe some other `.conf` file from `conf.d` directory has `listen 80 default_server;` directive in a `server` block and takes priority over this config?

Comment: @IvanShatsky that's the answer. I removed the default `include`s and everything started to work properly. Thanks!